# Symfony2 - How do you set the upload path outside of the bundle?

Tags: symfony, file-upload

I'm new to the whole launching live thing, I'm attempting to fix my file uploads, it seems to be uploading the file within the bundle. I need to upload the file to the public_html folder outside of the bundle.

Below are my functions what do I need to change so the uploadpath goes outside of the symfony project folder?

server folder setup:

```
/etc/
/symfony project folder
/public_ftp/
/public_html/ <--- this is where I want it to go


public function getUploadDir()
{
    return 'images/';
}

public function getUploadRootDir()
{
    return __DIR__ . '/../../../../web/' . $this->getUploadDir();
}

public function getWebPath()
{
    return null === $this->image ? null : $this->getUploadDir() . '/' . $this->image;
}

public function getAbsolutePath()
{
    return null === $this->image ? null : $this->getUploadRootDir() . '/' . $this->image;
}
```

Comment: That should already be uploading to `web/images/` which is outside of your `src` folder. Make sure the web server has the correct permissions to write to that directory

Comment: Are you moving the file there? I got this from the docs: `$this->getFile()->move( $this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->getFile()->getClientOriginalName() );`

Comment: Right but I am looking to move it out of the symfony project folder completely into the public_html folder. The original path is still inside of the symfony project folder. Updated question.

Comment: I understand now. I thought you meant you wanted them out of the Bundle, not out of the entire project. I have posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `getUploadRootDir` to:

```
public function getUploadRootDir()
{
    return __DIR__ . '/../../../../../public_html/' . $this->getUploadDir();
}
```

That will place your images into `public_html/images/`, if you want them directly in `public_html` then also update `getUploadDir` to:

```
public function getUploadDir()
{
    return '';
}
```

Comment: Bingo! Now can you explain to me how that worked? /../../../../../? Where does the folder destination start from?

Comment: @esteemed.squire `__DIR__` is the directory containing the current PHP script which is somewhere in your bundle, and you need to traverse up the tree several folders to get out of your Symfony project folder.

Comment: ok, but how did you know 5 '/../' would work? im trying to understand how you calculated this.

Comment: I just added one set of `../` to the existing 4 of them, because the previously reference folder `web` was one level too deep (it was in your Symfony project folder and `public_html` is one level higher).

Comment: *scratches head* I guess it would more sense if I knew where it started and counted folders. I'm in the symfony project folder, then you have web folder which is outside of the bundle. So and you have 4 of /../  Just don't understand where `__DIR__` is if thats the starting point.

Comment: `__DIR__` is the directory which contains the PHP script with the code in your question. A path similar to `symfony_project/src/Acme/DemoBundle/Entity`, except with your own Bundle name.

Comment: `__DIR__` is a [PHP magic constant](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

Comment: Oh, I see now...with your example, makes more sense. Thanks for explaining that to me uber pro. Cheers.